# Is internal url redirection security concern?

Tags: apache, security, redirect, ssl, https

I have a short url say http://su.in/fixed_pattern
On clicking above url, one can redirect to http://longdomain.com/longurl?variablename=variablevalue

Both domains su.in and longdomain.com are known and trusted servers. Is there any security risk, if I send short url on sms? Do I need to get given short/long url ssl enabled?

Comment: The risk is a phishing attempt, not the benign SMS with a valid short URL. Oce you train users to follow those short URLs from a SMS message, they will follow all of them - even the bad ones. And it does not matter if your organization does not send them. Once a user learns to follow them, they will continue to follow them. So you really need to fix a problem that's outside your control :o